# Freebsd porting and pkg-static

Tags: freebsd, compiling, packaging

I am porting makemkv to freebsd 10.2 and for this reason I wrote the following makefile:

```
# New ports collection makefile for:    makemkv
# Date created:             05 Mar 2012
# Date Updated:             10 April 2016
# Whom:                 kappei84
#
# $FreeBSD$
#

PORTNAME=   makemkv
PORTVERSION=    1.9.9
CATEGORIES= multimedia
DISTNAME=   ${PORTNAME}-oss-${PORTVERSION}${EXTRACT_SUFFIX}
MASTER_SITES=   http://www.makemkv.com/download/

# Prefix for the pkp-plist
#PLIST_SUB= DATADIR=${PREFIX}

# Missing qt4/qt5 dependency check in case the port is built with --enable-gui
BUILD_DEPENDS=  ffmpeg${FFMPEG_SUFX}:${PORTSDIR}/multimedia/ffmpeg${FFMPEG_SUFX}

MAINTAINER= 
COMMENT=    Make MKV from Blu-ray and DVD

GNU_CONFIGURE=  yes
OPTIONS_DEFINE= GUI

.include <bsd.port.options.mk>

.if ${PORT_OPTIONS:MGUI}
CONFIGURE_ARGS+=    --enable-gui
.else
CONFIGURE_ARGS+=    --disable-gui
.endif # GUI

# flags for the configure script
CPPFLAGS+=  -I${LOCALBASE}/include
LIBS+=      -L${LOCALBASE}/lib

MAKEFILE=   Makefile
USES= gmake
USE_OPENSSL=    yes
USE_LDCONFIG=   yes
USE_QT_VER= 4
QT_COMPONENTS=  qmake gui svg webkit xml moc uic rcc imageformats

do-install:
.if ${PORT_OPTIONS:MGUI}
    ${INSTALL_PROGRAM} ${WRKSRC}/out/${PORTNAME} ${PREFIX}/bin
.endif
.for i in libdriveio.so.0 libmakemkv.so.1 libmmbd.so.0
    ${INSTALL_PROGRAM} ${WRKSRC}/out/${i} ${PREFIX}/lib
.endfor
    @ cd ${PREFIX}/lib ; \
    ${LN} -sf libdriveio.so.0 libdriveio.so ; \
    ${LN} -sf libmakemkv.so.1 libmakemkv.so ; \
    ${LN} -sf libmmbd.so.0 libmmbd.so

.include <bsd.port.mk>
```

this makefile references the Makefile of the original application and it compiles and creates all the source files necessary to generate the three libraries *libdriveio.so.o*, *libmakemkv.so.1* and *libmmbd.so.0* wich are copied into */usr/local/lib* with the post install. Up until this step everything works perfectly as you can see from the log below:

```
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/makemkv-oss-1.9.9'
===>  Staging for makemkv-1.9.9
===>   Generating temporary packing list
install  -s -m 555 /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/makemkv-oss-1.9.9/out/libdriveio.so.0 /usr/local/lib
install  -s -m 555 /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/makemkv-oss-1.9.9/out/libmakemkv.so.1 /usr/local/lib
install  -s -m 555 /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/makemkv-oss-1.9.9/out/libmmbd.so.0 /usr/local/lib
```

What I do not get is the final phase which gets executed after the do-install, which is the registration phase:

```
====> Compressing man pages (compress-man)
===>  Installing for makemkv-1.9.9
===>  Checking if makemkv already installed
===>   Registering installation for makemkv-1.9.9
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libdriveio.so: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libdriveio.so.0: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libmakemkv.so: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libmakemkv.so.1: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libmmbd.so.0: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv/work/stage/lib/libmmbd.so: No such file or directory
*** Error code 74

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/multimedia/makemkv
```

as you can see some of the files (listed inside a file called pkg-plist) cannot be found under the expected path and the installation fails.

Is there any way to avoid or to change the default folder where the pkg-static is supposed to check? As it is the first port for me, is it necessary to perform this phase and have a pkg-plist or is it also possible to remove such a file as the main libraries have already been copied into the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile appears to be trying to install directly into `${PREFIX}`. This is *not* how things are done these days.

You should be installing to `${STAGEDIR}${PREFIX}`. This is a staging area under `${WRKDIR}` which mirrors the destination directories. The underlying stuff called by `make install` will take the files from there, and that's how the registration works.

Full details here:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/special.html#staging

but feel free to comment with any questions.